# Firefox spellcheck keeps changing dictionary to es_CU even after I changed to en_US in about:config

Tags: firefox, language-support, dictionary

Running Ubuntu 14.04, but happened with 13.10 too. Also tried disabling language add-ons but no es_CU is there anyway. The about:config change works until I restart.

Comment: Go to help >>> Troubleshooting information >>> reset firefox.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, despite having creating a *user.js* file in my profile directory with the following single line of content:

```
user_pref("spellchecker.dictionary", "en_US");
```

I fixed it by uninstalling *myspell-es*.  Since I still need to have a Spanish dictionary to use in LibreOffice, I downloaded and installed the [generico-america-latina-y-espana dictionary](http://extensions.libreoffice.org/extension-center/spanish-dictionaries) (although I had to rename it *generico-america-latina-y-espana.oxt* to get it to install).

See [this mozillaZine post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2865587) for full details, which may help anyone who has a similar, but not quite the same, problem.

Comment: It's a year later (Firefox 40 on Ubuntu 14.04)... but for what it's worth, when right-click here in this comment-editor box, and select `English (United States)` from the `Languages` , `about:config` shows the `spellchecker.dictionary` setting to be `en-US`, not `en_US`. Similarly, it uses a hyphen for the other variants, e.g. `en-GB`, `en-ZA` etc. So I wonder if putting "en-US" in your `user.js` would have made a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+T.

It will open a terminal window

Then enter 'su' it will prompt for root password. after that type firefox.  Make necessary changes now. and also have a look http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2865587

I will suggest you to reset firefox then apply the necessary changes. In  firefox menu bar go to help>troubleshooting information>reset firefox. It will reset the firefox.

Comment: By running Firefox as root, wouldn't you just be changing the root user's profile settings? Not to mention making it easier for malware to compromise security--I can't think of any good reasons to run a web browser as a superuser.

Comment: I still have problems with spell check in ubuntu 15.04.